# Microcontroller core voltage

Tags: microcontroller

Can someone provide me some explanation or clarity regarding the three internal voltage regulators that [this Microcontroller](http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/ref_manual/MPC5606SRM.pdf) has mentioned in chapter 40, page 1227.

From what I read, I think that we are not providing the core voltage (1.2V) to the micro directly. We are providing 3.3 to 5V and we place an NPN outside to get the 1.2V which is then fed to the Micro pins.

- is this correct?
- How does this work?
- If this is true, then the Micro Vcc is 5V only, right?
- And how by placing a NPN transistor and giving 5V to its collector, we get 1.2V at the emitter? How does the transistor do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd be better off reading the [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MPC5606S.pdf) instead of the user guide, but:

> We are providing 3.3 to 5V and we place an NPN outside to get the 1.2V which is then fed to the Micro pins.
>
> - is this correct?

Yes; the internal regulator generates 1.2V for the core.

The fact that these 1.2V are available externally is mostly so that you can (have to) connect decoupling/stabilizing capacitors, which can't be integrated into a silicon die.

> How does this work?

Linear regulator. Just like you can buy an LDO chip, that LDO can also be integrated into a microcontroller silicon chip.

> If this is true, then the Micro Vcc is 5V only, right?

No. How do you come to that conclusion? The datasheet clearly lists all the 3.3V supplies you need.

> And how by placing a NPN transistor and giving 5V to its collector, we get 1.2V at the emitter? How does the transistor do this?

That's basically the question of "how do I build a linear regulator with a NPN transistor". There's simply a device measuring the voltage at the emitter; if it's lower than it should be, the base voltage of the transistor is increased, if it's too high it's decreased, so that the differential resistance of the collector-emitter junction is "just right", so that the current draw leads to exactly the voltage drop across that junction that leads to the correct output voltage.

You can imagine (it's not going to be a full opamp inside the chip, but the principles apply) it working like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXfSt3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As a matter of fact, the Base-Emitter voltage of a standard NPN is usually pretty fixed (~0.7 V) for all relevant current draws, so that there needn't be a specific sense pin to sense the emitter voltage, if one can sense the base voltage relative to ground.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in assuming that there is only a single board level supply required for this microcontroller.
For the core power supply, it is not unusual to find this solution. The external NPN transistor provides the power part of a linear voltage regulator. All other things are  integrated on the chip's silicon. You only require the external NPN to dissipate heat and a an external capacitor to provide regulator stability.

Look into linear voltage regulators in order to understand how they work. You can also just assume that the chip drives the base in order to regulate the voltage as required.